# Call a spring jar library in a java project

Tags: java, libraries, buildpath

I created an application with Springboot that allow to sign documents on a distant server. 
This application can be called by another java / JEE application.

The entry point of the application is in the controller : 
public void createSignatureRequestData(Path fullPath, DocumentRestRequest documentRestRequest)

My objective is to import the library in another project, call the method in a main method (for test purpose) and retrieve the response at the end.

[image]

I imported the library and added it in the buildpath. My issue is that when I can't import the class which is situated in BOOT-INF/classes/com/certeurope/app/certeurope/ui/controller folder / package.

[image]

Comment: You cannot due to the format of the JAR. A Spring Boot application cannot be used as a dependency in another application. Instead you wold need to create a regular jar as well. This is all explained in the [Spring Boot Maven Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html) as well as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042062/spring-boot-application-as-dependency

Comment: indeed it works fine. I can access to the classes from now. My issue now is that i don't get the dependencies of the project which was maven.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that. You will get 2 jars now, 1 executable uber-jar (fatjar) the other only containing the classes no uber-jar.

Comment: it's just that i have errors that i shouldn't have : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at com.certeurope.app.certeurope.shared.utils.Pkcs12Reader.<clinit>... I have Lombok in my pom and It includes SLF4J

Comment: Again/still I don't know what you mean. You should have 2 jars one executable and one not. The not executable one is usable as a dependency, the other isn't. Also you shouldn't depend on transative dependencies in your code or expect yours to include the dependencies. What you probably should be doing is put the common classes in a seperate non-spring boot project and include this jar in both your projects.

Comment: I'm rewritting the app without using springboot and it works much more better